# Craft equivalent to Drupal Signups module

Tags: plugins, registration

I'm investigating a switch to Craft CMS for my non-profit as an alternative to Drupal or Wordpress. We're on Drupal right now, and our website gets used daily to sign up for public events that we host.

The functionality of the Drupal Signups module (ttps://www.drupal.org/project/signup), combined with the Events module, is one thing we'd be want to replicate if we moved to another CMS. Essentially, we want to enable:

a) registration for the event (name, email address, phone number that is temporarily stored -- we don't want to deal with usernames or passwords to sign into the site)

b) a registration cap (i.e. registration closes at 40 attendees)

c) confirmation emails, as well as reminder emails to be automatically sent to registered users that the event is coming up

d) the ability for staff to send a group email to all registrants in case the event is delayed/cancelled from within the CMS;

e) the ability for our staff to view and manage signups from the admin interface (i.e. delete a registrant if they want to cancel their spot)

I see that Craft has plugins such as Venti to handle the event side of things. Is there anything currently available that could similarly handle signups and reminder notices? Does anyone know of similar examples using Craft CMS for other websites?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For the calendar portion:

Solspace Calendar: https://solspace.com/craft/calendar

Craft Calendars: https://topshelfcraft.com/calendars/introduction

For the membership part it'd be pretty easy to just add the people who register onto the event itself